# How To Bulk Update Pivot Table For Same Attributes In Laravel Many To Many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-7

I just found out that when i'm using sync() method for updating pivot table from many to many table, it was executing multiple query.

[image: Screenshot from Laravel Telescope]

In my condition, i just trying to update same attributes for all related pivot table records.
This is my script :

```
foreach ($serials as $serial) {
    $newSerials[$serial['id']] = ['warehouse_id' => 1];
} 
$record->serials()->sync($newSerials)
```

Are there any other solution that can do update in pivot table in only one query shot in laravel with Eloquent way ?

I'm pretty sure Query Builder can handle this, but what i need to know in is Eloquent way, that maybe can combine with sync() method, because i alreay implemented sync() to the most of similar case like this in my project.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can, using newPivotQuery() which make the query run directly on pivot table,
you should prepare the array you want to add, give it key value pairs according to your pivot fields names, something like:

```
foreach ($serials as $serial) {
    $newSerials[] = 
['serials_id'=>$serial->id,'record_id'=>$record->id,'warehouse_id' => 1];
} 
$record->serials()->newPivotQuery()->insert($newSerials);
```

and there is another way, you can create model for the pivot table by inheriting from pivot, more details in:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

i must note that this code insert $newSerials, not updating them, if you want to update the record, method sync() is you best choice